# Testing view elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I am trying to test a value that is displayed on a page, the code that displays the value is:

```
<% @user ||= current_user %>
<div class="stats">
  <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
    <strong id="following" class="stat">
      **<%= @user.following.count %>**
    </strong>
    following
  </a>
  <a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
    <strong id="followers" class="stat">
      <%= @user.followers.count %>
    </strong>
    followers
  </a>
</div>
```

I am trying to use assert_equals as such:
assert_equals user.followers.count, (The followning value displayed)

But I am not sure how to reference the value that is displayed on the page.  Do I need to assign the value an id?  If so how would I right the reference to it in the test?

I hope I have provided enough information.

Regards,

Ryan.

Comment: I am not sure if it is clear from my post but the specific segment that I am trying to test is between the asterix (@user.following.count)

Comment: It would be helpful to post your test code as well. Also you might want to check out this section http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-views

Comment: Are you using fixtures in your testing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two scenerios (and you should be doing both):

- You want to verify the count calculated in controller.
- You want to test the view(HTML)

For part 1: Verify what your controller has, [**assigns()** gives you controller objects/variables](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/TestProcess/assigns).

```
assert_equals assigns(:user).following.count, 2
```

For part 2: As describe [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-views), to test your views use **assert_select**. like:

```
assert_select 'div.stats a strong#following', assigns(:user).following.count
```

Also you should replace **assigns(:user).following.count** with some hardocded number, so you always make sure that some other thing is not changing the following count.

Comment: Thanks for that, very helpful.